# iframe not showing the updated html page

Tags: html, css, iframe

An iframe link to an html page isn't updating on the page with the iframe when I edit the html page that is being linked to.

```
<div style="position: fixed; left:151; top:232;height:542px;width:826px;overflow:auto;background-color:#ff5a93">
<iframe src="indexsub.html" width="826" height="542" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" name="frame" id="mainframe"></iframe>
</div>
```

Here's the code I'm using, I copy and pasted this onto two other pages and they seem to be updating fine, I don't know the issue.

Comment: It looks like you faced with iframe url caching. Try to add some random variable to iframe url like that <iframe src="indexsub.html?x=8236482" width="826" .../>. Also did you try to add Expires, Cache-Control, or Pragma headers to main page and to frame page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a function in JS code which is refreshing the iframe:

```
function Refresh(){
var iframe = document.getElementById("IFRAME ID");
iframe.src = "NAME/LOCATION OF THE FILE";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to constantly refresh the page you publish as an iframe.

indexsub.html inline

```
setTimeout(() => {
  document.location.reload();
}, 3000);
```